# Python Tkinter: What syntax in main() will get the return value of a method bound to button in a class instance?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tkinter-entry

New to tkinter, I want a short program to:

- create a window to take user input, by means of an entry widget and a submit button
- capture the input and return it to main, so that I can do something else with it.

The following code creates the window and captures input, but breaks at the next-to-last line.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class TxtEntryWindow:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.root).pack()
        self.box = ttk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.box.pack()
        self.but = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Submit', command=self.capture_txt)
        self.but.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def capture_txt(self):
        txt = self.box.get()
        return txt


win = TxtEntryWindow()
user_input = win.capture_txt()
print(user_input)
```

Here's a copy of the error message:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > > File "C:...\wclass.py", line 22, in 
> > > user_input = win.capture_txt()
> > > File "C:...\wclass.py", line 17, in capture_txt
> > > txt = self.box.get()
> > > File "C:...\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 3072, in get
> > > return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
> > > _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"

I have no idea what this means. I suspect that dependence of "txt" on the button event in the class prevents "win.capture_txt()" in main() at the bottom from fetching the user input.
Can anyone shed light?

Consulted Python's official documentation (unintelligible), Tkinter's official tutorial and command reference. Searched numerous analogies on StackOverflow and on youtube. Googled the error message itself. I've tried to strike out on my own and rewrite the critical command about twenty times. Blind intuition leads nowhere. Stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the entry widget (`self.box`) has been destroyed when the line `user_input = win.capture_txt()` is executed.

You can use an instance variable to store the input text instead and access this instance variable after the window is destroyed:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class TxtEntryWindow:

    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "" # initialize the instance variable
        self.root = Tk()
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.root).pack()
        self.box = ttk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.box.pack()
        self.but = ttk.Button(self.frame, text='Submit', command=self.capture_txt)
        self.but.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def capture_txt(self):
        # save the user input into the instance variable
        self.text = self.box.get()
        self.root.destroy()


win = TxtEntryWindow()
print(win.text) # show the content of the instance variable
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the behavior of Tkinter.

Comment: (2) Why is it necessary, in your revised version, to destroy the root window (or, if I delete that statement, why is it necessary for me to close the window manually) before the output displays? I had envisaged the window persisting so that multiple entries could be printed from the same box and button.

Comment: (3) Given that the window does have to be destroyed first, how is it that the variable "text" survives to be printed, when everything else vanishes?

Comment: Somehow my first point was lost when I saved my first comment. (1) What in my original code caused the entry widget (self.box) to be destroyed? Was it my "return" statement in the capture_txt() method?